# How to restrict access to EC2 Spring Boot based REST endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have static web hosted on AWS S3 and Spring Boot based REST application running on EC2.

How would I restrict access to EC2? Currently, I have opened access to world on 8080 port, but this is not what i would like to have when I migrate to production. If I do not open access to world, I have connection timeout error in the browser's console.

Is there some way to allow only S3 based bucket to see EC2 instance and revoke world access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the code isn't running on the "S3 based bucket", it is running in each of your user's browsers. So you have to allow access to the world since you don't know ahead of time each IP address of each user you will ever have.

You should look into something like [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) or [AWS Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) or  at least use API Keys.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the answer, could you please elaborate on your last sentence? Do you mean, that I have to have some kind of authorization on REST endpoints? I have password protected the REST endpoint, but I was not sure if this is enough.

Comment: What is "enough" entirely depends on how much you want to lock it down. "Enough" is a subjective term that is up to you to decide.

Comment: I agree, there is no enough when it comes to security. I guess I have done the minimum and need to tighten it more.